# Ubuntu - Postfix, Courier, MySQL and SquirrelMail: "ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server."

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, postfix-mta, squirrelmail

I've followed [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.04-lts) tutorial to setup a local mail server for my domain name.

Although, when finished and I try logging in, SquirrelMail gives me the error:

```
ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.
```

My mail.log says the following(where webmaster@example.com is my username):

```
Nov 10 23:45:58 example imapd: chdir example.com/webmaster/: No such file or directory
Nov 10 23:45:58 example imapd: webmaster@example.com: No such file or directory
```

Here is my main.cf file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = no
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = "The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 latest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, what is happening is your test email is getting circled in a loop of Antivirus and spamblockers none of which are working so it wont release it to create the folder you need.

in console you need to update your virus definitions for clamav -

Freshclam will retrieve virus definitions then you need to restart your virus protection

execute the following commands, then resend your test email and you should be able to load your email on squirrelmail.

/etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam restart

/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start

/etc/init.d/amavis restart

in case you don't remember; to do the test email type mailx  leave cc blank push enter type a subject push enter type a body push enter and ctrl D.

if these steps dont work you may have a problem somewhere else open your mail.log file

cd var/log

nano mail.log

then scroll to the bottom